# Batch - Take Multiple Arguments from User Input

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that takes arguments from user input when calling the batch from the command line. I'm not very good at batch, hence why I'm here. I have multiple files that I wish to use for compiling C++ code and what I need is a way to get multiple arguments without specifying how many are there.

```
echo | set /p=g++ -c %1\%2.cpp > run.bat
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0 >> run.bat
echo PAUSE >> run.bat
echo exit >> run.bat

start /wait run.bat
del run.bat

move %2.o %1\
```

Example run: `compile_sing helloworld main`

This compiles main.cpp in ..\helloworld\ and moves the generated .o file to ..\helloworld\.

I also have another batch that runs the program.

```
echo | set /p=g++ %1\%2.o %1\%3.o -o %1\%4 > run.bat
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0 >> run.bat
echo PAUSE >> run.bat
echo exit >> run.bat

start /wait run.bat
del run.bat

start %1\%4
```

Example run: `run_mult helloworldv2 main file2 execute`

This will create the executable `execute` and run it.

What I would like is a way to enter multiple file names without having to put %#. The number of files can range from 1-n.

For the second one, I'm sure i'll need a special character to put in front of the last argument to specify that it is the ending one.

Comment: [Learn](http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) about `SHIFT` command, batch processing etc. [here](http://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for the tip. I've added my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after learning `SHIFT`, thanks to the tip of [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz), I have my answer.

To compile multiple files, I used the following

```
set folder_path=%1
SHIFT
:start
echo | set /p=g++ -c %folder_path%\%1.cpp > run.bat
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0 >> run.bat
echo exit >> run.bat

start /wait run.bat
del run.bat
move %1.o %folder_path%
SHIFT
if not "%1"=="" (goto :start)

PAUSE
```

And to run the compiled files, I used the following

```
set folder_path=%1
set files=
set var=
SHIFT
:set_files
set files=%files% %folder_path%\%1.o
SHIFT
set var=%1
if not "%var:~0,1%"=="/" (goto :set_files)

echo | set /p=g++ %files% -o %folder_path%\%var:~1% > run.bat
pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0 >> run.bat
echo PAUSE >> run.bat
echo exit >> run.bat

start /wait run.bat
del run.bat

start %folder_path%\%var:~1%
```